# Trigger the button's onclick after checking that the cursor has been on it for some time

Tags: unity, gui

I would like to have the mouse hover/click the button for a fixed amount of time (5 seconds) before triggering the `onclick` method, it can click only after they have hovered for a certain amount of time on one button. I'm using it with the leap motion UI and EventSystem to prevent clicking a button by accident when passing the hand over it.
I tried using the highlight animation and then triggering the event after it but i can't check if the hand has passed through another button and then got back to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IPointerEnterHandler/IPointerExitHandler component.

I wasn’t sure from your question if you wanted it to automatically perform the click action after hovering, or only allow them to click after they have hovered for certain amount of time. This example automatically performs the button click action after five seconds of hovering.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HoverClick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public float ClickDelay = 5;
    //Detect if the Cursor starts to pass over the GameObject
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Invoke("doClick", ClickDelay)(
    }

    //Detect when Cursor leaves the GameObject
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        CancelInvoke("doClick");
    }

    public void doClick() {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry if i was vague in my description. I need to perform the click after they have hovered for a certain amount of time on a specific button.

Comment: So this example would work for you